# not able to ssh into ec2 (private ip) from my work station using dynamic inventory ec2.py

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory

brief description: I am trying to run an ansible-playbook with -i ec2.py. But it throws me ssh timeout error. Ansible did connect to aws and listed the ip address of the ec2 instance but it just fails to do ssh. here is the error that says ssh time out but also shows the ec2 instance ip (which is 10.0.1.205 )

```
fatal: [apache]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/user5/.ansible/cp/4a6f728a0f\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"10.0.1.205\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 10.0.1.205 [10.0.1.205] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 10.0.1.205 port 22: Connection timed out\r\nssh: connect to host 10.0.1.205 port 22: Connection timed out", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I do have a security group that opens ssh port 22

```
resource "aws_security_group" "web-sg" {

  name        = "allow_ssh"
  description = "Allow SSH inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.web-vpc.id

  ingress {
    description      = "SSH from VPC"
    from_port        = 22
    to_port          = 22
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_ssh"
  }               
}
```

I verified on this on the ec2 instance as well, so this security group is attached to the instance with inbound rule allowing ssh port 22 from any IP

I also ran `python3 ec2.py --list` to see the list of machines and it lists fine

I also ran `$ansible-inventory -i ec2.py --list` and this also listed the host `apache`, so definitely ansible is able to reach the aws, authenticate and have the host info. Just that it fails while `gathering facts` with ssh errors

posting some out from the list (my ec2 instance tag Name: apache)

```
 "platform_undefined": [
    "apache"
  ],
  "security_group_allow_ssh": [
    "apache"
  ],
  "tag_Name_apache": [
    "apache"
  ],
  "type_t2_micro": [
    "apache"
  ],
  "us-east-1": [
    "apache"
  ],
  "us-east-1d": [
    "apache"
  ],
  "vpc_id_vpc_0dfc1fc7e6895fc81": [
    "apache"
  ]
```

so ansible is able to connect to aws from local linux machine (outside of aws), but I am not able to ssh into the machine.

I did generate ssh key (rsa 4096) and placed public key on ec2 instance, and used private key in `ansible.cfg` file `private_key_file = /home/user5/.ssh/id_rsa`

any suggestions on why I am not able to ssh into the ec2 machine? I appreciate any help

### UPDATE:

After upgrading my `aws CLI` to latest version, I am able to SSH into the instance manually. This is the document that I followed to connect to the private IP address from my local machine https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/amazon-ec2-instance-connect-ssh-rdp-public-ip-address/

so this is the manual way I connected.
`ssh ubuntu@i-0287a97b2579f44d3 -i /etc/my_key -o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h'`

how do I pass this part to Ansible? (can I add this ssh argument somewhere in ansible.cfg? or .ssh/config or something?) `-o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h'`

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-connectivity-from-public-to-private-introducing-ec2-instance-connect-endpoint-june-13-2023/

**UPDATE 2**
I guess I installed and uninstalled, reinstalled too many things. Mine is CentOS 7 machine with Python3 (it also has Python 2.75 and also Python 3.4 and Python 3.6). Very latest aws cli
aws-cli/2.13.0 Python/3.11.4 Linux/3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64 exe/x86_64.centos.7 prompt/off

I think now if I can fix this error, I might be able to connect.

Thank you both Pierre B and Vasyl Heman for your inputs.

the error

`fatal: [i-0289a96b2xxxxxx]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/bin/aws\", line 19, in <module>\n    import awscli.clidriver\nImportError: No module named awscli.clidriver\nssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host", "unreachable": true}`

Comment: Have you tried SSHing into the machine manually? Also try running Ansible in verbose mode using `-vvv`, it might give you a more in-depth error message about the SSH process.

Comment: 10.0.1.205 is the private IP. Does the instance have a public IP?

Comment: no public IP. If I have a public IP, I connect it without any issues.Here is what aws is providing to access private IPs directly from your local machine (not a bastion, and outside of aws machine) https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/amazon-ec2-instance-connect-ssh-rdp-public-ip-address/

Answer (score 1):

> how do I pass this part to Ansible? (can I add this ssh argument
> somewhere in ansible.cfg? or .ssh/config or something?)
>
> ```
> -o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h'
> ```

You can use [`ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-args) such as:

```
export ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS="-o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h'"
```

Or in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = "-o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h'"
```

However the fact you cannot connect directly via SSH without passing special options may indicate a misconfiguration of your infrastructure - most likely a network issue preventing communication with instance (it can be a Security Group or something else). You can checkout [official doc on creating VPC and related resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/create-vpc.html) to check if you VPC is properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example https://github.com/PrettySolution/ansible-ec2-instance-connect

As Pierre already said `ssh_args` should be without double quotes in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h'
```

aws-cli/2.13.1 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/22.3.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off.
Python 3.11.4
ansible [core 2.12.1]

UPDATE:
the way I install [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html):

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Comment: Hi @Vasyl Herman, thank you for your response. I did fix ssh_args a few days ago but I think I installed to many packages with too many different versions on my Cent OS 7 machine. I am getting this error `import awscli.clidriver\nImportError`. I did install aws cli using pip3. Look the actual post for the complete error message and see if you can suggest something

Comment: Sure, @JBone. I updated my post as well. I don't think it is the root cause, just in case, can you give it a shot? Install awscli as docs recommends, clone my repo and run steps in the Readme.md. I am crossing my fingers it will work out.

Comment: Thank you @Vasyl. I already have that package (as you can see from my update2 in the question). Just that it is not picking up. I am not sure why

Comment: also know that I did reinstall like you suggested in your answer, and I still get the same error

Comment: @JBone, I've updated the repo and README. Could you, please, follow and see what is not working now?

Comment: @JBone, I'd suggest getting the example working first and then moving from there to your scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254529/discussion-between-vasyl-herman-and-jbone).